# robot_localization using UTM grid as map

Tags: imu, navigation, gps, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to use `robot_localization` in Groovy to fuse information from several sensors (IMU, turn rate sensor and GPS). I'm using version x.1.6 from the hydro-devel branch ([Check previous question regarding problems running in Groovy](http://answers.ros.org/question/197267/robot_localization-2nd-instance-not-publishing-map-odom-transform/)).

I've followed the tutorials from `robot_localization` (http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) and GPS integration (http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization). Two instances of `ekf_localization_node` are running. One fuses IMU and turn rate sensor data, and the second one fuses IMU, turn rate and GPS. world_frame of the 1st instance is set to odom, and world_frame of 2nd one is set to map.

IMU sensor provides roll, pitch, yaw and X,Y,Z accelerations. Turn rate sensor provides Z axis angular speed (yaw rate). GPS data is feed through the `navsat_transform_node`.

All testing has been made with the platform static (it is an USV that is for the moment dry-docked).

Everything seem to be working, as the respective TFs and topics are published but I have two issues:

**1.-** I expected that "map" frame would be the UTM grid and the map->odom TF would give me basically a filtered transformation between the UTM grid and odom (the output of the now deprecated `utm_transform_node`, gone through the EKF with the IMU and turn rate sensor). However, what it seems to give me is the drift of the odom frame with respect of the initial point which is (0,0) and not the original UTM coordinates that should be something around (582409, 4793246).

Is this correct? Is there a way to get that the second instance of the `ekf_localization_node` gives me that transformation (UTM map --> odom)?

If I use the `utm_transform node`, whould be the map->utm transform equivalent to what I'm looking for? It seems that `navsat_transform_node` doesn't publish the odom-->utm transform.

**2.-** Is it enough an IMU with accelerations to have good estimations with `ekf_localization_node`? The IMU I'm using (RPY and accelerations, plus yaw rate from other sensor) in static is giving some accelerations, probably because it is not perfectly planar, and the EKF seems to be integrating them without any filtering, so in a few minutes it is giving me speeds of Km/s. I undertand that this should be normal, as no other source of positioning is present, but it doesn't seem to be compensated at all by the GPS input in the second instance.

Is there any roll-pitch gravity compensation introduced in the EKF or is it necessary to introduce it before feeding the EKF with the accelerations?

I understand that it is still a feature under development, so I don't know if this question should be put here or in another forum.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I've fixed the errors pointed out in the comments (negative Z acceleration when static and using /imu/pseaa in navsat_transform_node). Results are now much better than before, but still the accelerations add up and in a couple of minutes I get a drift of more than 100m in X,Y.

I've also added a fake TwistWithCovarianceStamped to the EKF filters publishing 0 velocities with high covariance (though a lower covariance didn't seem to change te behaviour):

```
rostopic pub -r 10 cmd_vel geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovarianceStamped '{twist: {twist: {linear: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}, covariance: [10, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10]}}'
```

So, at this moment as sources we have:

1. A Twist message with 0 velocities.
2. An IMU giving RPY and accelerations in X,Y at arount 0.02 m/s² (I guess due not being perfectly planar) and in Z at around 10.4 m/s².
3. A GPS giving positioning that varies only in the 6th decimal degree (+- 2m, after transforming it to UTM).
4. A turn rate sensor giving an error of around 0.01 rad/sec.

All sources are reporting that it is static, with what looks like reasonable error. However, the EKF seems unable to compensate the error, and after a couple minutes, the position has drifted around 100m and the speeds are around 3m/s (and 3Km and 60m/s in Z axis).

Should be this the expected result? Should't be the EKF able to filter the sensor errors and keep the position static?

I have uploaded a bag file that can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p43ihxqmvrzsftq/2014-11-14-11-03-39.bag?dl=0).

The bagfile is 135 seconds long. In the 30 first seconds, there is only the output from the sensor and after that robot_localization is launched and /odometry/imu and /odometry/filtered are published. When the bagfile ends, the position in both topics has drifted as reported before.

**UPDATE 2:**

Just noticed that IMU covariances maybe are too small for the error it is actually giving. I will try to put higher ones and report back.

**UPDATE 3:**

Increasing the IMU covariance largely reduced the drift to a half, more or less. However, it is still huge (aprox 60m in a couple minutes).

**UPDATE 4:**

Added `/odometry/gps` message.

**UPDATE 5:**

Fixed the errors pointed in the comments:

- `navsat_transform_node` now listens to `/odometry/filtered` instead of `/odometry/imu`.
- "*gpsodom0*" changed to "*odom0*" in "map" ekf_localization_node (`ekf_localization_gps`).
- Created an small node that publishes *TwisthWithCovarianceStamped* with time stamp and frame_id = /base_footprint (sample message at the end).

Now it seems to be working as expected: Twist messages compensate the error on the IMU accelerations in the "odom" ekf instance and the GPS readings avoid the position to drift too much in the "map" ekf instance. This compensation works also when not using the TwistWithCovarianceStamped, in which case the odom frame drifts a lot, but the map frame remains close to the origin.

However, I have found that the compensation of the GPS is not exactly as expected. What I've appreciated is that, first, the the map frame starts drifting and, after some time, it stabilises and remains more or less static in some apparently random position, moving from it only whitin GPS error. This drifting is not always the same, sometimes it is very close to the origin, some other is more than 10 meters away. All tests are made under the same conditions, but the results from one to another are quite different.

A couple examples: In [this bagfile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/utcd7zhkgdyxq8y/2014-11-17-07-01-34.bag?dl=0), first, the map frame drifts slowly, until it stabilises at arount (14, -16). In [this other](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e4ctzq97m6kwsdg/2014-11-17-07-12-07.bag?dl=0), the map drifts much less and stays whithn a few meters of the origin. In theses bagfiles /cmd_vel topic is not used, but it is included in the bagfile.

Is this behaviour normal?

In my application, an error of  few meters in the global positioning is not a problem as long as odom frame is good enough, but an error in the order or tens of meters is too much.

Also, now I'm getting the following warning in the map ekf node:

```
[ WARN] [1416228236.448192519]: MessageFilter [target=/base_footprint ]: Discarding message from [unknown] due to empty frame_id.  This message will only print once.
```

I don't know what can be the soruce of this warning, as all topics seem to have frame_id. I also don't know what effect can have this on the ekf node.

**(UPDATE 5) Updated launch file:**

```
<launch>

<!--    IMU localization-->
    <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization_imu" respawn="true" output="screen">
        <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
        <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
        <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_footprint"/>      
        <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>                

        <param name="imu0" value="/imu/imu"/>
        <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true]</rosparam>
        <param name="imu0_differential" value="true"/>
        <param name="imu1" value="/imu/pseaa"/>
        <rosparam param="imu1_config">[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false]</rosparam>
        <param name="imu1_differential" value="false"/>
        <param name="twist0" value="/cmd_vel"/>
        <rosparam param="twist0_config">[false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false]</rosparam>
        <param name="twist0_differential" value="false"/>
        <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odometry/imu"/>
    </node>

<!--robot_localization: utm_transform_node, ekf_localization_node -->
    <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform_node" respawn="true" output="screen">
        <!-- Compass reports magnetic north-->
        <param name="yaw_offset" value="0"/>
        <!-- Magnetic declination in Pasajes: -0º 49' W (http://magnetic-declination.com)-->
        <param name="magnetic_declination_radians" value="-0.014253522"/>
      <!-- On level ground, your IMU should read 0 for roll. If it doesn't,
           enter the offset here (desired_value = offset + sensor_raw_value). -->
        <param name="roll_offset" value="0.02"/>
      <!-- On level ground, your IMU should read 0 for pitch. If it doesn't,
           enter the offset here (desired_value = offset + sensor_raw_value). -->
        <param name="pitch_offset" value="0.02"/>

        <remap from="/imu/data" to="/imu/imu" />
        <remap from="/gps/fix" to="/gps/fix" />
    </node>

<!--    GPS integrated localization -->
    <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization_gps" respawn="true" output="screen">
        <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
        <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
        <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_footprint"/>      
        <param name="world_frame" value="map"/>             

        <param name="imu0" value="/imu/imu"/>
        <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true]</rosparam>
        <param name="imu0_differential" value="true"/>
        <param name="imu1" value="/imu/pseaa"/>
        <rosparam param="imu1_config">[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false]</rosparam>
        <param name="imu1_differential" value="false"/>
        <param name="twist0" value="/cmd_vel"/>
        <rosparam param="twist0_config">[false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false]</rosparam>
        <param name="twist0_differential" value="false"/>
        <param name="odom0" value="/odometry/gps"/> 
        <rosparam param="odom0_config">[true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]</rosparam>
        <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
    </node>

</launch>
```

**Example of /imu/imu output**

```
header: 
  seq: 54278
  stamp: 
    secs: 1415891538
    nsecs: 881067037
  frame_id: imu
orientation: 
  x: -0.0138267071095
  y: 0.0068664070791
  z: -0.959724247099
  w: 0.280519240258
orientation_covariance: [1e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1e-06]
angular_velocity: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular_velocity_covariance: [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: -0.2548
  y: -0.2254
  z: -10.3488
linear_acceleration_covariance: [1e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1e-06]
```

**(UPDATE 1) Final /odometry/imu message in the bagfile (aprox 100 seconds):**

```
header: 
  seq: 3056
  stamp: 
    secs: 1415962914
    nsecs: 607047460
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_footprint
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -149.016141137
      y: -45.095185213
      z: 3573.57328201
    orientation: 
      x: 0.000870648461272
      y: 2.93825796934e-06
      z: -0.000700732886557
      w: 0.999999375468
  covariance: [8802.261111477996, -0.005788838569369977, 5.444902206855785, -3.840273544411622e-12, 2.5082517391441255e-09, 1.6506454847914552e-11, -0.005788838569369087, 8802.271754156352, -11.356349203451261, -2.508260913770995e-09, -3.84303696516608e-12, -5.483616850128093e-11, 5.444902206855782, -11.35634920345128, 17638.61274511664, -3.0400515647995436e-11, 1.004057461029083e-10, 0.0, -3.840273544411622e-12, -2.5082609137709947e-09, -3.0400515647995494e-11, 9.993481116512381e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 2.508251739144128e-09, -3.843036965166083e-12, 1.0040574610290828e-10, 0.0, 9.993481116512381e-07, 0.0, 1.6506454847914558e-11, -5.483616850128093e-11, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.996695826509655e-07]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: -2.8057898119
      y: -0.726292330684
      z: 70.1421818858
    angular: 
      x: 3.71348986853e-05
      y: -0.000336629444983
      z: 0.010646294744
  covariance: [2.5463296868001555, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.5463296868001555, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.092618308225821, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.007793185274937632, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.007793185274937632, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00024768868126744505]
```

**Example of /gps/fix:**

```
header: 
  seq: 28786
  stamp: 
    secs: 1415891697
    nsecs: 482672929
  frame_id: /gps
status: 
  status: 1
  service: 1
latitude: 43.287458
longitude: -1.98402266667
altitude: 193.7
position_covariance: [1.2100000000000002, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.2100000000000002, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.840000000000001]
position_covariance_type: 1
```

**(UPDATE 1) Last  /odometry/filtered message in the bagfile (after aprox 100 sec):**

```
header: 
  seq: 2938
  stamp: 
    secs: 1415962914
    nsecs: 611566163
  frame_id: map
child_frame_id: base_footprint
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -134.980940092
      y: -42.2113010159
      z: 3301.74562816
    orientation: 
      x: 0.000870741064745
      y: 2.78125021491e-06
      z: -0.000707626114296
      w: 0.999999370534
  covariance: [7822.053947085913, -0.005169207414691056, 4.922211730418841, -3.7242073374581155e-12, 2.411348508464105e-09, 1.59223380525217e-11, -0.005169207414698126, 7822.063312624678, -10.070601138861608, -2.4113572292972366e-09, -3.7268762749434515e-12, -5.206107264704302e-11, 4.922211730418825, -10.07060113886157, 15676.933289130826, -2.9328427884104475e-11, 9.534040799821162e-11, 0.0, -3.724207337458112e-12, -2.4113572292972386e-09, -2.9328427884104475e-11, 9.993481116512381e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 2.4113485084641085e-09, -3.726876274943456e-12, 9.534040799821181e-11, 0.0, 9.993481116512381e-07, 0.0, 1.5922338052521704e-11, -5.206107264704302e-11, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.996695826509655e-07]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: -2.66379304704
      y: -0.700978246536
      z: 67.4209537165
    angular: 
      x: 3.71350689302e-05
      y: -0.000336629340775
      z: 0.010646294744
  covariance: [2.4480686118481643, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.4480686118481643, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.896098910796469, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.007793185274937632, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.007793185274937632, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00024768868126744505]
---
```

**(UPDATE 1) Final /odometry/gps message form the bagfile**

```
header: 
  seq: 973
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: ''
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 2.33176480979
      y: 0.0612228550017
      z: -0.356700941047
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  covariance: [0.6406396378901923, -0.0005784933813285471, -0.03503371173521515, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.0005784933813285471, 0.6405231938216485, 0.03168475581723582, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.03503371173521514, 0.03168475581723582, 2.55883716828816, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

**(UPDATE 5) Example of TwistWithCovarianceStamped published in /cmd_vel:**

```
---
header: 
  seq: 236202
  stamp: 
    secs: 1416229824
    nsecs: 221582889
  frame_id: /base_footprint
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0]
---
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197374/robot_localization-using-utm-grid-as-map/) by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 329 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whew! Nice question. This answer might be a bit lengthy, so bear with me:

1. First, some history. The *utm_transform_node* originally published an *odom*->*utm* transform to the tf tree. Assuming your UTM data, which was reported as a nav_msgs/Odometry message, had a frame_id of *utm*, you could simply include it as an input to *ekf_localization_node*, and it would apply the transform before fusing the position. However, when a GPS device first starts up, it will naturally report some erroneous positions until it gets position information from enough satellites to give reasonable accuracy. The UTM data coming from *utm_odometry_node* in `gps_common` doesn't concern itself with that, so I added a new input to *utm_transform_node*, namely, the raw gps_common/GPSFix message. I used that information to determine if the fix was valid before computing the transform. At this point, though, I had [redundant information](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/issues/63), and so I nixed the requirement for UTM data, deprecated *utm_transform_node*, and created *navsat_transform_node.* *navsat_transform_node* still keeps a *world_frame*->*utm* transform internally, but it doesn't publish it. Instead, it outputs a nav_msgs/Odometry message with the data already converted to the world (in this case, *map*) coordinate frame. This provides two benefits:

- Users can just start up the node and get global positions that are consistent with their robot's starting position and orientation.
- rviz behaves a little strangely when you have a transform that's on the order of tens of thousands of meters, and this eliminated that issue.

Having said that, if you need navsat_transform_node to publish that transform, I'd be happy to add it as an optional, configurable feature. Just submit a [feature request](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/issues).

4. This is a little harder to answer without a bag file, but I do see a few issues in your configuration and sensor data:

- First, double-check your sensor data. To answer your question, yes, I am compensating for acceleration due to gravity. There's a parameter called *remove_gravitational_acceleration*, and it defaults to true. I should really make that a per-sensor configuration, but I digress. However, your IMU appears to be reporting *negative* Z acceleration on what I'm assuming is level ground. Is your IMU flipped upside-down, and if so, is that reflected in your *base_footprint*->*imu* transform? Double-check all of your signs for acceleration, because my correction could very well be causing your accelerations to increase. My assumptions about directions of acceleration readings are the same as [this](http://www.intantech.com/files/Intan_RHD2000_accelerometer_calibration.pdf). If the IMU is on a level surface, it should report Z acceleration of +9.81 m/s^2.  If you roll it +90 degrees, it should report a Y acceleration of +9.81 m/s^2. If you pitch it +90 degrees, it should report an X acceleration of -9.81 m/s^2.
- Second, your *navsat_transform_node* configuration uses the */imu/pseaa* topic, but in your *ekf_localization_node* configuration, you have its yaw value set to false. If that sensor doesn't have an absolute heading reference, it won't work. I would switch that to the *imu/imu* topic, which appears to have orientation data.

The first bullet may solve your problem. Please let me know if it doesn't, though, as I would expect your configuration to produce reasonable results.

Sorry, just thought of one additional thing: are you sending any cmd_vels (geometry_msgs/Twist) to your robot? If so, if you can get that data into a geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovarianceStamped message, you can fuse that into your state estimate as well (just give it a large covariance). After you ensure that your acceleration signs are correct, you can use that velocity data to help keep the acceleration from accumulating into massive velocities.

EDIT in response to new questions. I have not yet looked at the bag, and when I do, I will likely have a much more definitive answer, and will update this.

1. Re: your comment below (2/3): no. Following REP-105, *odom* and *map* are more or less the same, except that one (*map*) takes in global position data, and the other (*odom*) uses only continuous data that isn't subject to discrete jumps. At start, the map and odom frames are completely aligned. As the robot moves, they begin to drift from one another, as the *map* frame receives global position data, and the *odom* frame starts to drift from the effects of erroneous measurements. I treat the UTM grid as a completely separate frame. There *is* a *map*->*utm* transform that is stored internally to `navsat_transform_node`, but I'm not yet broadcasting it (to be remedied...).
2. When you report drift rates of 60m after two minutes, are you saying that (A) you measured the actual drift of the vehicle, (B) the covariance on X and Y is 60m, or (C) that the vehicle is stationary and you're seeing a position of 60m? I'm pretty sure you mean (C), but I wanted to be clear.
3. Re: your question about whether the filter should be able to keep the position static, the answer is that it's only going to be as good as the input data. Your accelerations are noisy, yes, but they are almost certainly *not* zero-mean, so even if the filter is able to sort out the "true" value of the acceleration, it won't account for biases. In other words, if your accelerometer is reporting X linear acceleration of 0.2 m/s^2 +/- 0.04 m/s^2, the EKF will figure out that your true acceleration is 0.2 m/s^2, but won't account for the fact that it ought to be 0. BUT (and I think this may be good news)...
4. I'm very suspicious of your GPS data. The fact that you are getting `ekf_localization_node` positions into the tens or hundreds of meters indicates that your GPS data is almost certainly not being fed into the filter. Can you post the value of /odometry/gps? Global position measurements will always constrain your drift, so even if you have massive false velocities, every GPS measurement will bring your estimate right back home.

EDIT 2:

OK, found some good stuff. I'll start with the biggest issue.

1. I should have caught this before, but your GPS odometry configuration for your "map" instance of robot_localization needs a small but important change. You have this:

   ```
   <param name="gpsodom0" value="/odometry/gps"/>  
   <rosparam param="gpsodom0_config">[true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]</rosparam>
    <param name="gpsodom0_differential" value="false"/>
   ```

You need this:

```
    <param name="odom0" value="/odometry/gps"/>  
    <rosparam param="odom0_config">[true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]</rosparam>
    <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
```

`ekf_localization_node` only looks for parameters that start with "odom", "twist", "imu", and "pose." It will completely ignore a "gpsodom" prefixed topic.

2. Your cmd_vel topic has no frame_id or time stamp.
3. In your configuration for `navsat_transform_node`, you should probably remove your `<remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odometry/imu"/>` line, which will make it listen to the odometry from your "map" instance of `ekf_localization_node`, which is publishing the `/odometry/filtered` topic. The output `frame_id` of `navsat_transform_node` will match whatever odometry topic to which it is subscribed, and you want that `frame_id` to be "map."

There may be more things to tweak, but let's start with those. I'm still having trouble with the message time stamps. Are all the messages originating on the same machine?

EDIT 3 (response to update 5):

You are experiencing drift that is purely a result of your GPS data. I took the liberty of plotting the raw GPS data for both runs and centering it around 0 so you can see the drift in meters.

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

I didn't rotate it into your frame, but your run that showed (14, -16) has approximately the same magnitude (21.26 meters) as the plot below (whose magnitude is ~20.88 meters).

Disregard the warning message. That's a minor bug that really only makes that message print, but thanks for bringing it to my attention!

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2014-11-14**:
(1/3) Thank you for pointing these errors. The negative Z acceleration is probably a mistake by me when converting the raw IMU data to an IMU message, and using the pseaa instead the imu probably was the 112342345235 change...
I will fix them and try it again right now. (follows in next comment)

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2014-11-14**:
(2/3) Regarding the first issue, I will submit the feature request, but, for the time being, if I use utm_transform_node will I get map->odom with map in UTM coordinates?

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2014-11-14**:
(3/3) Finally, cmd_vels are actually sent to the robot, but being a USV catamaran with differential thruster steering, the inertia and drift are so huge that I thought that it would do more damage than good. Moreover, the USV is dry-docked, and I will be unable to move it at least until next week.

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2014-11-14**:
Edited the question to add a sample of /odometry/gps message. Just noticed that it doesn't have any timestamp. Maybe the messages are being discarded because of that?
Regarding your second question, yes, I mean (C). As mentioned, the platform is dry-docked and it can't be moved.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-14**:
The timestamp thing is actually a bug and I've created an issue for it (thanks for pointing that out!), but it shouldn't account for why it's not being integrated. I'll let you know when I check out the bag.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-14**:
Question: is there a reason why your time stamps on your messages seem to disagree with ROS time? Even when I play back the bag file with --clock and have use_sim_time set to true, there is nearly an hour's difference in each message's time stamp and the ros:Time::now() time.

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2014-11-17**:
(1) and (2), Wow, pretty big mistakes. I think that "gpsodom" was copypasted from some tutorial, but I didn't realise that it wasn't literal...

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2014-11-17**:
(3) I though that navsat_tranform_node needed the input of the ekf instance already running, as the second instance starts running after it. Seems I was (again) mistaken.
I will try theses changes and report back.
Thank you very much.

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2014-11-17**:
The one hour diference in timestamps I'm pretty sure that has been caused because the bagfile was recorded from an external computer used for monitorizing, which is not time synchronized with the one actually doing all the processing. It should't affect the result of the localization, though.

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2014-11-17**:
Made a bunch of tests and now everything seems to be working pretty much as expected! Thank you very much!
However, I still have some additional questions about what seems an extrange behabiour of the second ("map") instance. Please check the updated question for details.

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2014-11-17**:
Actullay, the GPS reception is not so good where the USV is placed right now, but I didn't notice that it was so imprecise. O_o
Everything is working correctly now!
Thank you very much for your help!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-17**:
You're welcome. Good luck with your project!

**Comment by [ASoriano](https://answers.ros.org/users/20687/asoriano/) on 2014-11-26**:
Hello IvanV, can you share your tf tree? I'm just trying to add an IMU and GPS sensors to robot_localization. But i'm not sure how i have to publish the tf's.
Thanks in advance and best regards!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-26**:
@ASoriano, feel free to post this as a new question. Tag it with robot_localization and I'll respond.